# Select 2 ajax search fires when pressing ctrl keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have the following select 2 field:

```
$("select#edit-property-id").select2({
  multiple: false,
  width: 150,
  delay: 250,
  placeholder: "Type",
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  ajax: {// instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's 
  // convenient helper  
    url: "/tell/product_chosen_search",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        term: params.term, // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
  },
});
```

The ajax search fires correctly when I enter characters, however it also fires when I press keys such as ctrl, down button etc... How can I prevent that? Is there a setting?

Comment: You want `openOnEnter: false`, see ticket https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a defect in the new 4.0 version of Select2, which is still in beta.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xptkthvs/)

With v3.5.2, the following line in the `updateResults` function prevents the unnecessary ajax calls:

```
// prevent duplicate queries against the same term
if (initial !== true && lastTerm && equal(term, lastTerm)) return;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqapq8ze/)

Here's a [somewhat related issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2446). At least, I think both issues could be fixed at the same time. You may want to add a comment to that issue.